# I want to use the argparse/sys for my custom class

Tags: python-3.x, argparse, sys

A brief version of my custom class, this class reads a .txt file and return an output accordingly.

```
class MyClass:
     def some_method(self, arg1, arg2):
                pass
```

I need to give the solution in this form, this is my `main.py` file

```
def main():
    input_file = sys.argv[1]
    # parse the file and process the command
    # print the output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I need to read the file from `sys.argv[1]`.

CLI should work like this:

```
python -m main <absolute_path_to_input_file>
```

I am not able to figure out how should I approach this?

Comment: What happens when you try what you wrote above?

Comment: why do you need / want to use argparse?

Comment: I can use sys as well. But I am not able to figure it out how to read a text file from sys.argv[1]

Comment: Looks like your `main` gets the filename correctly.  Now you have to pass the variable `input_file` to a file reader.  It's not evident from your `MyClass` definition how this is relevant to the task of read a file.  Is it supposed to take a filename as some argument?